# Meaning of "cut out (scheme-theoretically)"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $V$ be a projectively normal closed subvariety of some projective space over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $R$ be the local ring at the vertex of the affine cone over $V$ ($R$ is obtained by localizing the homogeneous coordinate ring $\mathbb{K}[V]$ at the maximal ideal generated by all the homogeneous elements of positive degree). Samuel showed that

> the class group $\operatorname{Cl}(Spec(R))\cong \operatorname{Cl}(V)/(\text{hyperplane section})$

Consequently,

> $R$ is a UFD $\Leftrightarrow$ every irreducible codimension $1$ subvariety of $V$ is cut out (scheme-theoretically) by a hypersurface of the ambient projective space.

I want to understand what does it mean by "cut out (scheme-theoretically)"? The meaning of the sentence is not clear to me.

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: see definition 13.7 in https://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/09-10/Autumn/18.725/l_13.pdf